# Save state of radio button android

Tags: android, radio-button

im working on an exam application

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVEc4.png

if the user choose a item and go to next question and after that go back to previous question the item which the user chose won't save

in this case what should I do???

note -> each question has a id which the name of that is question number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you can simply create a hashmap which stores the answer user chose. And then retrieve it by id when users get back

```
HashMap userAnswers = HashMap<String, String>()
userAnswers.put("id") = "answer"
String userAnswerAtId = userAnswers.get("id")
```

Comment: @HamidReza I'm glad that it helped you. Can you give my answer an upvote